# How do you call a var-function in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I’ve got a var function that checks the database for the username, but I don’t know how to call it in Node.js.

This is what I’ve got sofar:

```
// Get user_name from post.
app.post("/api/exercise/new-user", function(req, res) {
    let user_name = req.body.username; // Gets the URL from the body of the page.

    //Call findPeopleByName here.
});

// Check the database if user exists.
var findPeopleByName = function(userName, done) {
    User.find({username:userName}, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
           done(err);
        }
        done(null, data);
    });
};
```

Comment: `findPeopleByName(yourArgs)` ??

Answer (score 1):

It's a function that expects a callback. So to use it, call it with the parameter and a function that it will execute when it's done. The callback will be the `done` function in `findPeopleByName` which it will call after it has received data from `User.find()`

```
app.post("/api/exercise/new-user", function (req, res) {
    let user_name = req.body.username; //Gets the URL from the body of the page.
    findPeopleByName(user_name, (err, result) =>{
        if(err) {
            //handle error
            return
        }
        // use result
        console.log(result)
        // res.send() etc...
        })            
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your function `findPeopleByName` should be defined before its call. Second, to call this function, not really knowing what you want the callback `done` to be, `findPeopleByName(user_name, done)` should work if you replace `done` by the function you want to be call inside `findPeopleByName`.